# Not able to boot

Tags: 12.04, boot, 13.04, windows

Few days ago I was using windows 8 and it was pretty slow for 4gb ram and struck now and then.  Revently it became too slow but I didn't install anything so I tried to install windows 7 with the CD.

Everything went well until every time at last when windows has to boot it just keeps blinking or says press OK to .... from CD or DVD even if I press OK nothing happens  . So I downloaded Ubuntu 13.04 I tried Ubuntu from live usb I could access files so bravely i installed it after formatting windows drive (not other drives from the Ubuntu desk.)

I Gave ext4filesystem and / to mount. I think I made the mistake here instead of giving my 320gb internal I gave sda3 which had my windows, now even Ubuntu doesn't boot when i use my bootable pen drive it says

```
cannot open root device "null" or unknown block(0,0) error -6
Please append a correct "root=" boot option,.........
Kernel panic - not syncing :VFS: unable to mount .....
```

I want my data I don't have any backup and want to install Ubuntu is there any possible way or am I too late?
Help me.

Oh my god now when I again tried to install windows  7 it says no drives were found.windows 8 cd struck at logo.

Comment: Now I tried to repair with windows 7 disk and clicked load drivers it opened and only a 32mb disk was shown named boot. What happened to the rest 320 GB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is odd. It's also something I have seen already. The windows partition tables may be corrupt. Gparted may be a solution. It has the ability to rebuild partition tables, but I don't know about windows 8. If you have the windows 8 disk, i would suggest using it's repair feature. Windows 8 will reinstall itself and your data would be lost.

Last time I saw this, the customer tried install 7 beside 8 and interrupted the install. I solved it by using the windows 8 disk to repair the damage windows 8. It erased the 7 completely. After this, I partitioned the drive out for 7 and ubuntu then installed them both in each own partition.

Gparted will not work if you have your windows 8 in fast boot mode because it hibernates the system.

Comment: Thanks for your reply now the windows 8 disk won't work it's stuck in windows logo. What do I do?

Comment: Sorry for the slow response. You will have to loose your data at this point. If you can get access to dban and use it to erase your hard drive, then you can reinstall your windows 8. Then partition correctly out your partitions and install 7 and ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! I now have corrected. I had actually made the partition non-dos so windows didn't boot and live USB got corrupted so Ubuntu displayed the error message.